# How do I set a width and height variable to the browser windows width and height?

Tags: javascript

Im building a pong clone, and I would like the playable area to be the same size as the browser window.

```
var width = 400,
    height = 600;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this:

```
var width = window.innerWidth,
    height = window.innerHeight;
```